# Get values from a column within a column of a 3-level multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble with multidimensional arrays in PHP.

I'm assuming this should be simple but, I'm having difficulty wrapping my mind around the multi-dimensions.

The array that I have looks like this:

```
[
    ['projects_users' => ['project_id' => 1]],
    ['projects_users' => ['project_id' => 2]],
]
```

I would like to somehow alter this array to look like this, where all I see is an array of the project_id:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = ...
$new_arr = array();
foreach ( $arr as $el ) {
    $new_arr[] = $el['projects_users']['project_id'];
}
```

Or, with PHP version >= 5.3:

```
$new_arr = array_map(function ($e) { return $e['projects_users']['project_id']; }, $arr);
```

A third fun way, with [`reset`](http://php.net/reset):

```
$arr = ...
$new_arr = array();
foreach ( $arr as $el ) {
    $new_arr[] = reset(reset($el));
}
```

###Performance

Out of curiosity / boredom I benchmarked the iterative / functional styles with and without `reset`. I was surprised to see that test 4 was the winner in every run — I thought that `array_map` had a bit more overhead than `foreach`, but (at least in this case) these tests show otherwise! Test code is here.<s>`http://pastie.org/2183604`</s>

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2010 12:15:07) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
$ php test.php
Test 1, Iterative - 34.093856811523 microseconds
Test 2, array_map - 37.908554077148 microseconds
Test 3, Iterative with reset - 107.0499420166 microseconds
Test 4, array_map with reset - 25.033950805664 microseconds
$ php test.php
Test 1, Iterative - 32.186508178711 microseconds
Test 2, array_map - 39.100646972656 microseconds
Test 3, Iterative with reset - 35.04753112793 microseconds
Test 4, array_map with reset - 24.080276489258 microseconds
$ php test.php
Test 1, Iterative - 31.948089599609 microseconds
Test 2, array_map - 36.954879760742 microseconds
Test 3, Iterative with reset - 32.901763916016 microseconds
Test 4, array_map with reset - 24.795532226562 microseconds
$ php test.php
Test 1, Iterative - 29.087066650391 microseconds
Test 2, array_map - 34.093856811523 microseconds
Test 3, Iterative with reset - 33.140182495117 microseconds
Test 4, array_map with reset - 25.98762512207 microseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrays as $array){
    $new[] = $array['projects_user']['project_id'];
}

print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is important that indexes match, you will want to do something like this.

```
foreach ($orig_array as $key => $value) {
   $orig_array[$key] = $value['projects_users']['project_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can also be accomplished by using array destructuring syntax in a bodyless loop.  Notice that the subarray keys are accessed and where the targeted deep value is located, write `$result[]` to push that value into the result.

The benefit of this approach is that there is no need to declare a third/temporary variable (only the input and the result variables are declared).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cDAOh))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['projects_users' => ['project_id' => $result[]]]);
var_export($result);
```

---

To only declare the input variable, you can arrive at the desired result by calling `array_column()` twice.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iYiHG))

```
var_export(
    array_column(
        array_column($array, 'projects_users'),
        'project_id'
    )
);
```